# How to format date and time in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a column of date_timestamp with different date and time formats in oracle, now I'm having problem with converting them to just one format instead. May I ask how do I deal with this? I don't exactly know how many date and time formats are there in that column, there maybe this format:
'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mi:ss' AM OR this 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss AM' OR this 'YYYY-MON-DD hh:mi:ss AM' OR more. That's my problem. The column is in varchar data type. I have to put it in another column with a date data type. I used this code:

```
    UPDATE SCHOOL_BK        
    SET SCHOOL_TIMESTAMP = to_char(to_date(SCHOOL_TIMESTAMP,'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mi:ss AM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss AM')
    WHERE VALIDATEPAYMENTDATE(SCHOOL_TIMESTAMP) = 'Invalid';
```

This the VALIDATESCHOOLDATE function code:

```
    SELECT TO_DATE(SCHOOLDATE,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss AM') INTO sDate FROM dual;
    RETURN 'Valid';
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN 'Invalid';
```

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: That's why you don't store dates as strings.  If you don't know all the permutations, then how do you test for them?  You are on the right path by creating a function to validate.  Maybe in there, have a collection of date formats, iterate through them and try to convert until one works or all fail.

Comment: This just serves to highlight just how fatally flawed it is to store a date/time in anything but a DATE or TIMESTAMP column.  Even when 'testing' several possible formats, what is the proper interpretation of '01-02-03'?   What is the year, what is the month, and what is the day?  Even given '04-05-2022', is that May 4 or 5 April?

Comment: The thing is I'm not the one who made that, and I'm here to correct that mistake done.